# MKMapView delegate method are not getting called - Routes not being display on map

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, mkdirection

I would like to display the route from the one location to a second location. I have created some methods. The first one is to getDirection(), second is to createDirectionRequest and the rendererFor method. I am calling the getDirections method in my viewDidLoad. However when I run it, it seems that nothing is getting call. I added a print statement in both methods but they are not getting display on the console. Is it related to the thread.

Thanks for all replies and explanations

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        mapViewOutlet.delegate = self
        getDirections()
        settingImageRating()
```

```
func getDirections (){
        guard let location = locationManager.location?.coordinate  else {return}

        let request = createDirectionRequest(from: location)
        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

        directions.calculate { [unowned self] response, error in
            guard let unwrappedResponse = response else { return }

            for route in unwrappedResponse.routes {
                self.mapViewOutlet.addOverlay(route.polyline)
                self.mapViewOutlet.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
            }
            print("get direction")

        }
    }
```

```
 func createDirectionRequest (from coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> MKDirections.Request{
        let doubleLatitude = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: (business?.coordinates.latitude)!).doubleValue
        let doubleLongitude = NSDecimalNumber(decimal: (business?.coordinates.longitude)!).doubleValue

        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source =  MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: locationManager.location!.coordinate))
        request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: doubleLatitude, longitude: doubleLongitude), addressDictionary: nil))
        print(request.source!)
        print(request.destination!)
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
        request.transportType = .walking
         print("create direction")

        return request
    }
```

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: overlay as! MKPolyline)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
        return renderer
    }
```

Comment: https://medium.com/devzy/ios-draw-polyline-via-mapkit-in-swift-9cdac6ceeecf

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check that you set delegate in`Stroryboard` for MKMapView and in `UIViewController` file set delegate like `class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate`.

I tried this code and it's working fine for me.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var MKMapVW: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.showRouteOnMap()
    }

    func showRouteOnMap() {

        let coordinateOne = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(exactly: 40.586746)!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(exactly: -108.610891)!)
        let coordinateTwo = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(exactly: 42.564874)!, longitude: CLLocationDegrees(exactly: -102.125547)!)

        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinateOne, addressDictionary: nil))
        request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinateTwo, addressDictionary: nil))
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = true
        request.transportType = .automobile

        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

        directions.calculate { [unowned self] response, error in
            guard let unwrappedResponse = response else { return }

            if (unwrappedResponse.routes.count > 0) {
                self.MKMapVW.addOverlay(unwrappedResponse.routes[0].polyline)
                self.MKMapVW.setVisibleMapRect(unwrappedResponse.routes[0].polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView!, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
        if overlay is MKPolyline {
            let polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue
            polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 5
            return polylineRenderer
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```